# How to divide into two groups?

Tags: c

Here I has some problem to divide the grouping in C code. Below is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (){
int inp;
inp = 15;

signed int cx[15], cy[15];
cx[0] = 1;
cx[1] = 7;
cx[2] = -2;
cx[3] = -3;
cx[4] = -2;
cx[5] = -2;
cx[6] = -10;
cx[7] = 0;
cx[8] = -1;
cx[9] = 8;
cx[10] = 9;
cx[11] = 10;
cx[12] = -7;
cx[13] = 12;
cx[14] = 11;

cy[0] = -8;
cy[1] = -1;
cy[2] = -10;
cy[3] = -8;
cy[4] = -6;
cy[5] = -10;
cy[6] = 12;
cy[7] = 0;
cy[8] = 5;
cy[9] = -1;
cy[10] = 13;
cy[11] = -10;
cy[12] = 3;
cy[13] = 13;
cy[14] = 0;

int j;
printf ("\n Input (x,y) :\n\n");
for (j=0; j<inp; j++){
printf ("   X%d :(%d,%d)\n",(j+1),cx[j],cy[j]);}

printf ("\n Initial value of 2 centers :\n");
printf ("\n   Y1 = X1 : (%d,%d)\n",cx[0],cy[0]);
printf ("   Y2 = X2 : (%d,%d)\n",cx[1],cy[1]);

printf ("\n Objects-centers distance :\n\n");
for(j=2; j<inp; j++){
float dis1, dis2;
dis1 = sqrt((cx[j]-cx[0])*(cx[j]-cx[0])+(cy[j]-cy[0])*(cy[j]-cy[0]));
dis2 = sqrt((cx[j]-cx[1])*(cx[j]-cx[1])+(cy[j]-cy[1])*(cy[j]-cy[1]));
printf("   X%d -> Y1 : %.5f\t X%d -> Y2 : %.5f\n", (j+1), dis1, (j+1), dis2);}

printf ("\n Objects gouping :\n");

}
```

How to divide into two groups? The first group is the point closest to the first center point and the second is a point that is closest to second center point.

Comment: This is quite unreadable. Please indent your code and use spaces between operators.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by groups. Are you asking for groups or points?

Comment: I has 15 points, then I has declare first and second points as a center point. After that I has calculate distance between other points to center points. Lastly, I want divide each points in two groups refer to center points.

Comment: Nope. Just want try it. I stuck to divide it.

Comment: Did you mean clustering by any chance? The `centerPoint` will change dynamically to reflect the average(the centroid) of the group right?

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of ways to solve this problem.

The most simplistic is to simply create a third array, sized the same as the first two.  Each element will correspond to each `cx`/`cy` pair, and the value will be `0` if that pair is closer to the first point and `1` if it's closer to the second:

```
int result[15] = {0,1,0};  // points 2-14 initialized to 0

if (dis1 < dis2)
  result[j] = 0;
else
  result[j] = 1;
```

So if you want to see if point 4 is closer to point 0 or point 1, you just check the value of `result[4]`.

Comment: Or may be according to the OP, his *center-point* isnt really fixed!

Comment: where i need enter this code? sorry, i really noob about programming. i need someone for help and monitor me.

Comment: hello, somebody help me please.

Comment: You would create the `result` array in the same place you create your `cx` and `cy` arrays.  Then you'd add the `if` statement after you compute the two distances.